# Should I control health loss with the deltaTime? C++/SDL2

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I would like to know if it is a good idea to use the deltaTime of my program (the change in milliseconds between the current time the program has been running and the time the program has been run since the last iteration of the gameloop) to control health loss in enemies.

So instead of doing this:

```
...
enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth() - 5);
...
```

I do this:

```
...
enemy.setHealth(enemy.getHealth() - (5 * deltaTime));
...
```

The idea is to make health decrease at a similar on other computers but is this necessary?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: capping fpses might be a nicer solution.

Comment: Do you mean capping as in using SDL_Delay() to delay the program?

Comment: Capping limits higher rate, but not lower (e.g. so many things happen in frame and target machine cannot render it at cap framerate and logic will slow down - although I've seen games that behave that way, but it feels clunky). There are only two solutions I'm aware of - fixed (i.e. performing calculation at fixed time intervals, regardless of frame rate) and multiplying by actual passed time (your `deltaTime`). For some things one solution may be better (e.g. physics almost always calculated at fixed step), but for given task there is no clear winner. Choose the one you like more.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D. But is it really required? Will not doing this cause instabilities when running on other computers? I mean, I haven't seen this done anywhere before, so does it actually matter?

Comment: Frame rate, if not capped (via vsync or any other means), changes depending on how much you draw, and that is rarely a constant. Moreover, your program is not the only one running at any given moment, so sometimes you might get less processing time. If FPS is capped - that might not be a problem, but as I've said before sometimes you don't reach a cap. In all these cases you don't want any thing that is supposed to happen in known time to take different amount of time, or worse - fluctuate between fast and slow actions. I'd say it should be a requirement not to depend on actual frame rate.

Answer (score 1):

You have to determine what is appropriate behavior for your game.  If you use deltaTime as a scaling factor for the health loss, 1) you must use floating point health and 2) if there is a CPU hiccup (like another program hogs the CPU), all of the enemies might die in a single frame.

If you throttle your framerate and assume a constant time step, you can ensure a bit more control over the simulation.  If some test hardware doesn't hit your desired FPS, you can consider increasing the time step at the risk of losing temporal precision.